# Which statistics should I use?

Tags: inference, biostatistics

I have some medical research in which I have two set of data
1) control group [people who have no ailment]
2) study group [people who have some particular ailment]

Within each category there are subgroups like age, gender, blood pressure ranges, cholesterol ranges...

Now I have some observations (around 50) for both control group and study group. I have observations of various quantities like blood pressure, cholesterol level etc. I want to prove statistical significance of these quantities (blood pressure/ cholesterol) in study group. What is the best way to do it? Should I use a t-distribution or a normal distribution?

Also when I calculate the p-value, should I compare each subgroup in study group (based on range) with corresponding subgroup in control group or calculate one p-value as a whole for study vs control group?